# Why is SSMS 2008 prompting me "if you are certain that you have added all the necessary full-text catalogs, click OK"

Tags: sql-server-2008

When I try to attach a database in `SQL Server Management Studio 2008` (SSMS), I get prompted by this message:

```
If you are certain that you have added all the 
necessary full-text catalogs, click OK.
```

Why is this coming up.  It didn't use to.

We did make some schema changes but have done nothing with full-text catalogs.

Is there a way to prevent this coming up?

Comment: Are you attaching a pre-2008 database with FT enabled onto SQL Server 2008? You will need to attach FT catalogs which were separately backed up. From 2008 onwards, the FT catalogs are part of the database itself. If you don't attach the necessary catalogs, you will have to recreate the full text indexes to rebuild the catalogs.